# Const Char array being modified to all 0s for AVR micro written in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, avr, microprocessors

I am helping a friend get a graphics LCD working on his AVR, a few months ago all was working without issue, it has been untouched since then. The chip has now been swapped out from an ATMega32 to an ATMega164P. Essentially the same chip with more flash, since this change a lot of the code has stopped working.

We have narrowed where the error is occuring, but are unable to rectify it. It is where we pass in a pointer to a const char string, and attempt to print that string, however for some reason the stack(heap, something else?) gets corrupted and the pointer contains all zeros. Does anyone have any ideas how this could occur? We have -O1 level optimisations enabled which are required for correct timing, we have switched to winAVR compiler as well with no changes. We also do not have access to a debugger, and only have limited 'print' style debugging.

Here is the section of code that is causing issues:

```
//in the header file that is included
int SGCTEXTStringF(int column, int row, int font, int colour, const char* text);

//Call the function
SGCTEXTStringF(0, 0, 0x10, SGCColour(255,255,255), "text");

//Function
int SGCTEXTStringF(int column, int row, int font, int colour, const char* text){

unsigned char bytes[23]={0};

//...Code to communicate with LCD and set up a 'print string'

if(text[0] == 0) {
    bytes[6] = 'a'; 
    bytes[7] = 't';
    bytes[8] = 'e';
    bytes[9] = 's';
    bytes[10] = 't';
}

//..more code to finish sending the array
}
```

Now the display prints 'atest' when the code is run, this is showing that the const char array is being some how zero'd? I have also tried the following lines which also all print 'atest'

```
if(text[1] == 0)   //prints 'atest'
if(*text== 0)      //prints 'atest'
if(text != 0)      //prints 'atest'
```

This shows that it gets a valid pointer, but it appears to point to all zeros.

We also tried changing the call to the method to:

```
const char * string = "test";
SGCTEXTStringF(0, 0, 0x10, SGCColour(255,255,255), string);
```

This code was known to be working a few months ago, we even have a video of it running, now every single function in the program exhibits the same issue, char arrays being passed (on the stack?) don't seem to work and get cleared to 0s.

I can arrange to host a copy of the complete source code if anyone is interested. Any help or pointers at all are appreciated!

Comment: It looks like some kind of linker problem. Perhaps string literals are not being linked in at the correct address, or at all. I would look at the resulting binary and verify that it indeed contains all the needed literals. Also try to print out and verify their addresses.

Comment: Check size of the stack. If it is too small you can get such strange behavior. Also, can you show definition of SGCColour?

Comment: And recheck your map file (linker can generate it). May be something wrong with the section for "const data" (where C-strings are placed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATMega164P is not the replacement for the ATMega32 but for the ATMega16. For the ATMega32 you would need the ATMega324P.
If you are using the memory map for the ATMega32 (which has double EEPROM, SRAM and flash), your string may have landed in memory which simply does not exist.
For porting issues you may look at the [porting guide](http://atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc8001.pdf) from Atmel.

Comment: The correct chip has been selected when compiling, what other options are there to change?

Comment: Must just be running out of memory.

Comment: evice: atmega164p
               Program:    3398 bytes (20.7% Full)
               (.text + .data + .bootloader)
               Data:        886 bytes (86.5% Full)
               (.data + .bss + .noinit)   Looks like plenty of free space?

Comment: Check the linker options or config file to correctly match the 164P memory map, it must be different from the 32. If the locator puts some variables into non-existing memory areas, you'll have problems, even when the linker reports no problems and plenty of free memory. Quote from my link: "The ATmega164P/324P/644P
internal data SRAM addressing starts at 0x100 as opposed to 0x60 in ATmega16/32."
And you may need a different version of crt0.s (or the appropriate startup code usually provided by the compiler vendor) for the 164P.

Comment: We checked the output and SRAM was 114% full after the changes, it however doesn't think this is an error and successfully programs the chip.

The SRAM is only 1kb hence the issue, more than 1 or 2 nested function calls with 256byte buffers and you stack overflow.

Fixed the issue by making every single array in our program static and global forcing it to be stored in program memory and not in SRAM.

Comment: Memory map was correct, just has less SRAM hence the issue. Cheers for putting us on the right path though :)

Comment: Hmmm... What is the name of this site again? Weird errors - Always check for stack overflow.